# how to group by column a but order by colum b in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I trying to group one column and order by another column
my data is
carts

```
id product_id created_date group_id
1.   34         17:00:01      1
2.   35         17:00:02      1
3.   36         17:00:03      2
4.   37         17:00:04      1
5.   38         17:00:05      2
```

and i expect result like this

```
id product_id created_date group_id
1.   34         17:00:01      1
2.   35         17:00:02      1
4.   37         17:00:04      1
3.   36         17:00:03      2
5.   38         17:00:05      2
```

my sql that i write is not working

```
select group_id, product_id, created_date from carts group by group_id, product_id, created_date order by created_date
```

Comment: You don't appear to be doing any grouping.

Comment: Do you want records having same group_id together but ordered by their created_date ?

Comment: @AnandVidvat Yeap!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to order by 2 columns - first the group, then the creation date:

```sql
SELECT id, product_id, created_date, group_id
FROM table
ORDER BY group_id, created_date
```